# Convert image/jpeg file sent as image/jpeg via REST API to AWS Lambda into a usable format

Tags: google-apps-script, file-upload, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-textract

**CURRENTLY**

I am trying to send an image file to Lambda via API, such that it can be onsent to Textract.
Textract requires the file to be converted to "bytes", which I successfully achieved with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69868101/1730260 but this code sent the file as a string, which only works for small files. Larger files converted to strings get too big i.e. bigger than 10MB, and then API Gateway will not accept.

So, instead, I am trying to send the image file in blob format.

I have a REST API request from Google Apps Script that looks like this:

**Google Apps Script js:**

```js
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);
  let files = folder.getFiles();
  let file = files.next();
  let package = file.getBlob();

  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
       "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
    },
    payload: package,
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api_address",options);
```

**API Gateway Configurations**

- Type: `LAMBDA_PROXY`
- Content Encoding: `false`
- Binary Media Types: `image/png` `image/jpeg`

**AWS Lambda js:**

```js
"use strict";

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");


exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let file = event.body;
  console.log("file:"+file)

  let textract = new AWS.Textract();
  let doc = params["doc"];
  let config = {
    Document: {
      Bytes: Buffer.from(file), //<--- this is where issue is happening
      FeatureTypes: ["TABLES"],
    }
  };
  textract.analyzeDocument(config, function (err, data) {
    console.log("analyzing...");
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
    // an error occurred
    else {
      console.log("data:" + JSON.stringfy(data));
    } // successful response
  });
}
```

**Console Log Output:**

```
file: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....

UnsupportedDocumentException: Request has unsupported document format
```

**NOTES**

- if I stringify the payload in the request, the size gets above 10MB and returns error `HTTP content length exceeded 10485760 bytes`

**REQUEST**

This is the format I need to get my code working (as it worked before with a different smaller image):

```
-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,96,0,96,0,0,-1,-31,0,34,69,120,105,102,0,0,77,77,0,42,0,0,0,8,0,1,1,18,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-37,0,67,0,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,3,3,3,3,3,6,4,4,3,5,7,6,7,7,7,6,7,7,8,9,11,9,8,8,10,8,7,7,10,13,10,10,11,12,12,12,12,7,9,14,15,13,12,14,11,12,12,12,-1,-37,0,67,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,12,8,7,8,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,-1,-64,0,17,8,0,-96,1,86,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,-1,-60,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-1,-60,0,-75,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,-127,-111,-95,8,35,66,-79,-63,21,82,-47,-16,36,51,98,114,-126,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-31,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-1,-60,0,31,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-1,-60,0,-75,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,-127,8,20,66,-111,-95,-79,-63,9,35,51,82,-16,21,98,114,-47,10,22,36,52,-31,37,-15,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-126,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-1,-38,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,-3,-4,-94,-118,40,0,-94,-118,51,64,5,20,102,-118,0,40,-93,52,102,-128,10,40,-93,56,-96,2,-118,51,70,104,0,-94,-116,-47,64,5,20,81,64,5,20,102,-118,0,40,-93,52,80,1,69,20,80,1,69,25,-93,52,0,81,70,115,70,104,0,-94,-118,40,0,-94,-116,-47,-102,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-93,52,102,-128,10,40,-51,20,0,81,69,25,-51,0,20,81,69,0,20,81,69,0,20,81,69,0,20,81,65,25,20,1,-7,47,-1,0,7,25,-1,0,-63,121,-11,111,-8,39,-57,-123,116,95,3,-4,18,-15,39,-128,117,47,-120,-98,32,-110,-10,-49,93,-100,106,16,106,58,-105,-126,-68,-91,-73,104,-53,-39,-85,31,46,105,68,-20,80,-36,46,-36,68,112,-115,-37,-33,-2,15,-2,-35,30,27,-8,-7,-1,0,4,-127,-43,-75,15,11,-4,92,-16,-25,-117,62,38,120,119,-32,-16,-44,-11,-7,52,95,18,-63,121,-84,-23,26,-127,-46,89,-102,107,-127,4,-122,88,38,-13,-43,-50,91,107,7,83,-36,87,-28,23,-4,29,-25,-1,0,4,-11,-16,111,-20,-51,-5,68,120,87,-30,-42,-123,-87,120,-102,-21,-60,-97,27,-81,-11,75,-67,118,-38,-2,-26,9,44,109,26,-46,59,4,-116,90,-94,66,-114,-128,-119,91,119,-104,-14,100,-127,-116,119,-5,-53,-2,9,-13,-1,0,4,-110,-8,111,-5,4,-1,0,-63,37,-66,38,124,81,-16,126,-75,-29,125,75,-60,31,25,-66,10,-117,-19,110,-33,89,-68,-74,-102,-50,-43,-37,74,-106,-28,-117,101,-118,-34,39,85,-33,51,-113,-99,-36,-32,47,57,-55,60,77,-33,47,-83,82,91,-21,126,-23,-88,-67,23,-111,-76,-76,-59,80,75,-82,-53,-70,-26,87,111,-51,108,121,7,-4,26,45,-5,108,-8,-5,-29,38,-105,-5,69,106,-1,0,25,62,46,120,-61,-59,90,71,-123,32,-48,110,34,-68,-15,-97,-118,110,47,-83,-76,120,-33,-5,75,-51,117,-110,-22,86,88,85,-74,38,-30,8,7,98,-25,-96,-81,-39,47,-126,63,-75,47,-61,63,-38,94,-38,-10,-29,-31,-57,-60,111,2,-4,65,-73,-45,89,82,-18,79,13,-21,-10,-102,-78,90,-79,-28,9,12,18,56,66,123,3,-118,-2,90,-1,0,-32,-34,95,-8,37,-60,-65,-16,85,-1,0,27,124,74,-16,63,-119,60,127,-30,-97,7,-4,39,-47,98,-45,-75,79,18,105,-38,4,-47,-59,117,-81,93,-122,-71,91,21,-52,-120,-15,-127,22,110,95,115,-58,-8,36,0,-71,109,-53,-42,-4,22,-8,53,117,-1,0,4,93,-1,0,-125,-103,60,39,-16,-49,-64,-34,46,-42,47,52,24,124,87,-91,120,125,-18,46,72,73,-75,29,55,86,-118,-40,-101,107,-91,-116,4,-112,-81,-38,83,-99,-95,119,-60,-110,5,66,6,-33,102,-93,-115,74,-16,-92,-43,-100,-94,-83,-14,73,107,-22,-1,0,-49,-56,-29,-42,49,-85,82,58,-14,-69,-65,77,54,-4,62,-13,-12,-61,-2,14,14,-8,89,-15,-125,-57,-97,-76,-33,-127,-18,62,29,-2,-38,31,13,-1,0,102,-99,46,15,15,121,119,90,23,-120,-2,46,94,-8,54,-29,86,-105,-19,50,-97,-76,-91,-68,10,86,101,-38,66,121,-121,-100,-95,94,-43,-6,-65,117,-81,89,-8,79,-62,-115,-88,106,-102,-123,-99,-91,-115,-115,-65,-99,115,123,115,58,-57,12,72,-85,-106,-111,-92,98,0,80,50,75,19,-46,-65,-100,79,-8,61,27,63,-16,-33,31,9,73,-1,0,-95,47,-113,-4,14,-72,-81,90,-1,0,-125,-51,60,115,-15,19,72,-16,-41,-64,-51,5,103,-43,97,-8,67,-86,-59,115,62,-93,21,-95,49,-61,123,-87,-60,-47,20,73,-37,5,75,44,37,-102,37,110,50,101,108,29,-68,112,81,111,-22,112,107,-19,84,-102,-41,-90,-69,-73,-67,-69,47,67,-94,-92,111,93,47,-18,39,-89,-53,75,126,-89,-20,111,-122,63,-32,-92,95,-77,-65,-115,60,81,30,-121,-93,124,122,-8,47,-85,-21,83,73,-28,-57,97,101,-29,109,50,123,-87,31,56,-38,34,73,-117,19,-98,49,-116,-26,-67,-81,-17,-118,-2,109,-4,47,-5,59,-1,0,-63,37,-1,0,110,-81,-128,-70,95,-123,-68,15,-29,-83,87,-10,117,-8,-101,42,64,127,-74,60,93,119,-88,25,81,-112,15,53,110,77,-52,-25,76,111,49,67,-1,0,-86,-106,44,57,82,-72,31,35,126,-23,127,-63,58,127,101,-85,31,-40,-33,-10,71,-16,-97,-128,116,111,-120,-98,38,-8,-95,-96,-23,118,-34,102,-107,-83,-21,87,80,93,72,-10,-78,124,-15,-57,12,-112,-94,-125,108,-96,-2,-20,51,57,85,96,-95,-54,4,11,-73,37,-94,-17,-70,-47,118,126,-116,-61,-38,93,-85,117,-35,117,94,-89,-69,63,8,107,-14,7,-32,31,-62,-49,-116,86,31,-16,95,75,-3,123,80,-3,-75,62,27,-8,-117,-31,-21,120,-105,90,-111,62,15,-37,-4,93,-66,-68,-42,-96,-123,-84,-18,-124,86,-89,67,101,-14,85,-32,98,-110,52,121,-60,98,34,-61,-107,21,-6,-5,39,-6,-93,-12,-81,-26,-109,-10,55,-1,0,-107,-56,-75,-81,79,-8,78,-4,83,-49,-3,-62,-11,10,-116,42,-26,-58,-58,31,-35,-109,-5,-83,-45,-11,53,-83,-90,26,114,-13,95,-87,-3,24,124,88,-8,-35,-32,-33,-128,126,23,58,-25,-114,-68,91,-31,-113,6,104,-95,-4,-77,-88,107,-70,-84,26,117,-82,-20,19,-73,-51,-103,-107,115,-128,78,51,-40,-41,55,-16,115,-10,-42,-8,57,-5,67,-21,114,105,-65,15,-66,45,124,52,-15,-34,-95,18,-105,123,95,15,120,-98,-53,84,-103,64,25,36,-92,18,-69,0,7,-75,127,55,-65,-16,88,-17,-118,-102,76,-33,-16,113,6,-83,15,-19,117,97,-29,111,16,124,24,-16,-19,-36,80,-40,-24,-6,68,-51,9,26,59,-38,-122,-73,107,113,-67,9,-119,-25,59,-90,49,58,-69,17,48,86,-36,-95,107,-24,-49,-121,127,-16,76,-1,0,-8,38,-17,-19,-9,-15,-37,-64,122,-73,-20,-43,-5,67,95,124,19,-42,-76,-55,-48,73,-31,-21,93,78,-14,-41,90,-44,-18,-53,6,-127,-84,95,86,-109,-49,75,-108,96,-64,-104,60,-27,63,41,10,-72,-36,-58,30,-11,35,25,-67,-91,-37,116,-68,-41,127,33,86,-3,-37,113,-66,-85,-85,-39,-7,35,-6,6,92,-48,79,56,-23,89,-2,28,-45,38,-48,-4,59,99,99,54,-95,121,-85,77,103,111,28,18,95,93,-120,-59,-59,-37,42,-123,50,-55,-27,-94,71,-67,-120,-36,118,34,-82,73,-62,-127,-127,89,127,22,116,29,115,-59,-97,11,-68,67,-91,-8,103,92,-113,-61,30,35,-44,116,-21,-117,109,51,87,-110,-48,94,46,-105,114,-15,-78,-59,112,97,44,-94,79,45,-56,109,-123,-128,59,113,-102,-102,-115,-59,54,-75,-73,-30,58,122,-38,-3,78,71,-29,47,-19,-73,-16,103,-10,116,-41,-93,-46,126,33,124,91,-8,103,-32,93,86,104,-60,-47,-39,-8,-121,-59,22,58,93,-60,-120,122,48,-114,121,81,-120,-29,-82,49,93,87,-62,-17,-116,-34,17,-8,-29,-31,72,-11,-17,4,-8,-85,-61,-66,49,-48,-26,109,-111,-22,58,30,-91,14,-95,105,35,0,9,2,88,89,-112,-112,8,-17,-36,87,-32,42,127,-63,-75,-33,2,126,2,-8,-69,-57,26,-41,-19,-91,-5,93,-23,54,122,-10,-85,124,111,-76,-87,52,-49,19,89,-23,122,-90,-92,-81,-103,38,-70,-68,93,70,41,-26,-106,121,29,-119,-39,18,-74,54,-106,50,57,124,39,-127,-1,0,-63,-74,127,19,-96,-3,-97,127,-32,-68,-119,-32,63,-121,-98,49,-44,60,65,-16,-33,-59,-105,58,-26,-122,-105,107,27,67,23,-120,-84,109,-83,-82,-82,44,-18,100,-123,-62,-107,111,-36,35,-126,84,50,-17,97,-128,25,-123,107,-121,-118,-87,63,103,125,108,-35,-42,-38,43,-40,49,30,-28,28,-29,-78,105,107,-66,-67,79,-22,112,114,42,-98,-67,-81,-39,120,91,70,-70,-44,-75,75,-53,93,55,79,-79,-119,-89,-71,-70,-70,-103,97,-122,-34,53,25,103,119,98,21,84,14,73,39,2,-82,-109,-111,95,-126,-97,-16,122,-81,-114,-2,35,104,-10,-33,6,116,17,54,-83,15,-62,29,85,-81,39,-44,34,-76,38,56,47,117,56,-98,50,-119,59,96,-87,101,-124,-77,68,-83,-58,76,-83,-125,-73,-114,122,-110,105,-58,11,121,59,93,-20,-68,-39,116,-29,-51,123,-10,-71,-5,3,-31,-97,-8,41,23,-20,-17,-29,79,20,71,-94,104,-65,30,-66,11,-22,-38,-44,-46,121,49,-40,89,120,-33,76,-72,-70,119,-50,54,-120,-110,98,-60,-25,-116,99,57,-81,89,-15,71,-118,116,-65,2,-8,103,80,-42,-75,-115,66,-57,72,-47,-76,-101,105,47,111,-81,-81,110,18,-34,-38,-54,8,-44,-68,-110,-53,35,-112,-88,-118,-96,-77,51,16,0,4,-109,95,-50,79,-122,63,103,127,-8,36,-73,-19,-43,-16,19,74,-16,-65,-127,-4,117,-86,-2,-50,-65,19,38,72,15,-10,-49,-117,-81,53,3,42,50,1,-26,-83,-55,-71,-100,-23,109,-26,0,-1,0,-22,-91,-117,14,84,-82,7,-56,-33,-85,-66,49,-3,-105,-84,127,99,-113,-8,32,-17,-59,79,1,104,-1,0,17,60,75,-15,59,65,-45,62,25,107,-14,105,90,-34,-75,117,5,-52,-113,107,38,-99,59,-57,28,50,66,-118,13,-80,7,-9,97,-103,-54,-85,5,14,80,32,91,-81,-5,-70,51,-101,-34,59,118,122,116,100,97,-1,0,121,86,20,-42,-46,122,-9,71,-45,62,12,-3,-74,126,13,124,71,-16,22,-79,-30,-81,14,-4,91,-8,103,-81,-8,95,-61,-82,-79,-22,-70,-66,-101,-30,-117,27,-85,13,49,-40,101,86,121,-29,-108,-57,17,35,-96,118,25,-83,-97,-126,-1,0,-76,-89,-61,-81,-38,75,73,-70,-44,62,30,120,-13,-63,-98,61,-80,-79,113,21,-59,-49,-121,53,-69,109,86,24,28,-25,10,-17,3,-72,83,-63,-32,-98,-43,-4,-73,127,-63,-67,127,-16,72,104,-1,0,-32,-81,30,34,-15,-18,-125,-29,111,28,120,-53,-61,127,9,-4,10,109,117,11,-51,55,67,-70,88,-28,-44,53,43,-107,-98,56,29,4,-55,36,8,-55,28,50,-18,-112,-60,-49,-126,-86,48,27,35,-109,-15,55,-20,-83,-15,27,-2,9,-7,-1,0,5,-84,-15,39,-20,-33,-16,63,-30,87,-119,60,51,117,-30,-83,94,-33,-64,-42,-6,-22,-56,18,-22,77,47,85,-114,6,-1,0,72,-14,-128,5,-93,-114,117,37,-93,8,-37,-94,-34,-98,91,109,-58,-114,-101,85,85,30,-78,87,75,-18,-33,-17,-5,-75,38,82,92,-110,-102,122,65,-21,-23,-1,0,13,-8,-24,127,84,-6,119,-19,-89,-16,119,87,-8,-78,-34,0,-76,-8,-79,-16,-42,-21,-57,107,49,-73,111,13,-59,-30,123,39,-43,-42,65,-43,13,-88,-105,-50,-36,61,54,-26,-67,57,8,-57,-14,-81,-27,-85,-2,14,0,-1,0,-126,6,120,51,-2,9,23,-16,87,-31,-97,-114,-68,1,-29,111,25,107,-17,-81,106,-115,-93,-21,63,-37,-113,110,-52,47,4,6,104,-25,-74,48,-57,25,-119,15,-107,54,81,-116,-124,124,-97,63,28,-2,-42,126,-53,67,-30,-97,-4,20,35,-2,8,65,-32,56,116,95,-119,87,94,7,-8,-103,-29,-65,4,91,89,-65,-116,94,-35,-81,46,-94,-111,72,-118,105,-2,89,35,113,52,-79,-58,-29,-51,13,-71,26,77,-29,44,5,102,-41,-18,37,86,58,-72,-76,-97,77,89,95,-14,-10,49,122,41,43,-90,-9,-75,-19,-87,-12,87,-60,-65,-8,40,47,-64,95,-126,-98,48,-72,-16,-1,0,-116,-66,55,124,35,-16,-106,-65,104,64,-97,77,-42,-68,97,-89,88,94,67,-98,70,-24,-91,-103,92,117,-18,43,-46,60,29,-29,-67,23,-30,71,-123,-19,117,-65,14,-22,-6,94,-67,-92,95,-89,-103,107,127,-89,93,71,117,109,114,-67,50,-110,33,42,-61,32,-14,15,106,-2,117,127,-30,29,63,-39,67,-10,76,-8,59,-30,24,-1,0,106,47,-38,-41,67,-48,126,41,90,-51,119,37,-75,-121,-122,-4,65,98,-111,91,68,1,16,121,-106,51,-37,-55,125,115,33,32,59,-120,-62,99,126,-59,-55,30,99,65,-1,0,6,93,124,109,-41,116,-97,-37,39,-30,-121,-61,120,-75,-117,-55,-68,39,-86,120,81,-11,-1,0,-80,18,126,-51,-10,-69,123,-69,88,22,-31,84,-97,-111,-52,119,12,-89,3,-26,1,119,125,-59,-59,81,-116,106,115,65,61,82,-67,-42,-37,106,-67,73,-84,-35,52,-90,-74,-70,86,-21,-85,74,-25,111,-5,41,126,-38,63,24,-68,71,-1,0,7,92,-21,31,14,-11,15,-117,31,18,-81,-66,31,71,-29,63,18,90,-89,-123,-18,60,79,123,46,-116,-80,-59,-89,95,60,81,-117,54,-108...
```

How do I convert the string currently in my console log to the above format?

Comment: If you want to convert the blob to the byte array for Google Apps Script, how about modifying `let package = file.getBlob()` to `let package = file.getBlob().getBytes()`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getbytes) But If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, it is a different result, but still not accepted by textract: `LzlqLzRBQVFTa1pKUmdBQkFRQUFTQUJJQUFELzRTREdSWGhwWmdBQVRVMEFLZ0FBQUFnQUJnRVNBQU1BQUFBQkFBWUFBQUVhQUFVQUFBQUJBQUFBVmdFYkFBVUFBQUFCQUFBQVhnRW9BQU1BQUFBQkFBSUFBQUlUQUFNQUFBQUJBQUVBQUlkcEFBUUFBQUFCQUFBQVpnQUFBTUFBQUFCSUFBQUFBUUFBQUVnQUFBQUJBQWVRQUFBSEFBQUFCREF5TWpHUkFRQUhBQUFBQkFFQ0F3..."

My question was to see if I could convert the format into the one I shared, but I will also consider seeing if Textract will accept another format.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor Ensligh skill. I had thought that you wanted to convert `file.getBlob()` to the byte array like `-1,-40,-1,,,,`. From your replying, do you want to convert `file.getBlob()` to the base64 encoded data or another data? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? Or, for example, how about `let package = file.getBlob().getBytes().join(",")`?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are struggling with the API-gateway limit, then a better way would be to use [Pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

You can upload upto **5GB** with this method.

You can create a dedicated bucket for this purpose and configure a trigger.
As soon as a file is uploaded to bucket, lambda will be triggered and it can process your image.

You can upload the image in any appropriate format that you want.

[image]